# Django query for foreign keys

Tags: django, django-models

I have the model below, how do i get the postcodes given the `city id`?

```
from django.db import models

class City(models.Model):
    # ...
    pass

class Location(models.Model):
    # ...
    city= models.ForeignKey(City)

class Postcode(models.Model):
    # ...
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location)
    postcode = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this::

```
post_codes = Postcode.objects.filter(location__city__pk = city_id)
```

You can read more on [lookups that span relationships here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships). The `__` can span the foreign keys can be any level deep

Comment: I believe you can also use `location__city_id` to avoid one more DB lookup. [see the docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/optimization/#use-foreign-key-values-directly)

Comment: Not sure if it was clear, but I don't mean `id` vs `pk`, I mean `location__city_id` instead of `location__city__id`

Comment: Ok, but it is still going to be 1 query. What you are saying makes a difference only if you are doing lookups like `location.city.id` v/s `location.city_id`. And this is queryset filtering, and just 1 SQL query is generated

Comment: I tried it but didn't get the expected result. My query should be like this `SELECT postcode FROM locations_postcode a 
 LEFT JOIN locations_location b ON b.id = a.location_id
 LEFT JOIN locations_city c ON c.id = b.city_id
WHERE c.id = 172`

Comment: @karthikr its the `location__city__id = city` that works after reading the link you have provided. `city=172`

Comment: Ok.. Actually, even `post_codes = Postcode.objects.filter(location__city = city_id)` should work